# jQuery tab plugin not opening in a new browser tab when press 'ctrl' key

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have using Jquery easy tab plugin in my page.

When I right click on each tab and open it in a new browser tab it will showing up, but when I press `ctrl` key in keyboard and clicked on tab it will open in same browser tab instead of new browser tab.

How can I solve this?

my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
    var t = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if (t == "oilngas") {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabOil").trigger("click");
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else if (t == "utilities") {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabUtl").trigger("click");
    } else if (t == "smart") {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabSmt").trigger("click");
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else if (t == "heavy") {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabHvy").trigger("click");
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else if (t == "") {
        $(".offerings_content").show();
    }

    $("#oil_area").click(function (e) {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabOil").trigger("click");

        //prijesh
        //var href = $('#tabOil').attr('href');
        //var href = window.location.hash.substr(1);

        //alert("href : " + href);
        //if (href == '#oilngas'){
        //  window.location.href = href; //causes the browser to refresh and load the requested url
        //}


        return false;
    });

    $("#utility_area").click(function (e) {


        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabUtl").trigger("click");
        return false;

    });
    $("#smartbldng_area").click(function (e) {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabSmt").trigger("click");
        return false;

    });
    $("#heavy_area").click(function (e) {
        $(".offerings_content").hide();
        $("#tab-container").show();
        $("#tabHvy").trigger("click");
        return false;

    });
});
```

[Live page demo](http://flutura.com/flutura-trial/industriessolutions_trial.php#oilngas)

Comment: `return false;` on click handler is responsible for restricting redirection to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track whether `CTRL` key is pressed or not by maintaining some flag (which will be true/false whenever CTRL key is pressed.

```
var cntrlIsPressed=false;
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which=="17")
        cntrlIsPressed = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(){
    cntrlIsPressed = false;
});
```

Now using that `cntrlIsPressed` flag you can determine your return value:

```
$("#oil_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabOil").trigger("click");

    if(!cntrlIsPressed)
        return false;
});

$("#utility_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabUtl").trigger("click");

    if(!cntrlIsPressed)
        return false;
});
$("#smartbldng_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabSmt").trigger("click");

    if(!cntrlIsPressed)
        return false;
});
$("#heavy_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabHvy").trigger("click");

    if(!cntrlIsPressed)
        return false;
});
```

**EDIT:** 
You can also use `e.ctrlKey` to determine `CTRL` key status as [Kamlesh Kushwaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000051/kamlesh-kushwaha) suggested.

```
$("#oil_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabOil").trigger("click");

    if(!e.ctrlKey)
        return false;
});

$("#utility_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabUtl").trigger("click");

    if(!e.ctrlKey)
        return false;
});
$("#smartbldng_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabSmt").trigger("click");

    if(!e.ctrlKey)
        return false;
});
$("#heavy_area").click(function (e) {
    $(".offerings_content").hide();
    $("#tab-container").show();
    $("#tabHvy").trigger("click");

    if(!e.ctrlKey)
        return false;
});
```

**NOTE:** You'l also need to specify `taget="_new"` for your links as `<a target="_new" ...> ... </a>`

**EDIT:**
After seeing your page I can see that there isn't ID defined for your tab links, for [this page](http://flutura.com/flutura-trial/about_us_trial.php#company). Your tab plugin is preventing redirection.

You can refer links from their `href` attribute in jQuery selectory,  so you need to add following code open new tab from jQuery:

```
$("a[href='#company'], a[href='#founders'], a[href='#team'], a[href='#accolades'], a[href='#careers'], a[href='#philosophy']").click(function(e){
    //determine if control+click or mouse middle button
   if(e.ctrlKey==true || e.which==2){
        window.open($(this).attr("href"));
   }
});
```

This code I've tested from browser console on your page. Its working :)

Comment: its working fine when click center button of mouse but only in mozilla. when I press ctrl key its not showing up in new browser tab.

Comment: Its quite confusing. Do you mean its not working for middle button click?? For that you need to test `e.which==2` value.

Comment: @Dhanil, I got your problem. Try specifying `target="_new"` in your link `<a>` tags

Comment: I have tried that but it still not working. When i press ctrl key ane click on tab it open in the same browser tab.
check my page
http://flutura.com/flutura-trial/about_us_trial.php

Comment: whohhh!! its worked yahoooo!!! thank you brother/sister thanks a lot for your time!! one more problem this is very awkward to ask, when I press and click any inactive tab it open in a new browser tab its fine but it also opening that tab in that same page any solution for that ?? if not its fine .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52253/discussion-between-dhanil-and-log1c)

Comment: Hi, for that you can add `return false;` after `window.open(...)` statement. But I'm not sure, because your tab plugin is also interfering if its not working then you might have to edit their plugin code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.ctrlKey` . Check it's value, based on the value you can use `return false` or simply `return`